# Return columns and relative list

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have two tables:

Location
**tablename** = "location"

- loc_id: int
- name: str
- users = relationship(...)

User
**tablename** = "user"

- user_id: int
- username: str
- locations = relationship(...)

And associate table:

```
user_location = Table(
  "user_location",
  Base.metadata,
  sa.Column("user_id", sa.Integer),
  sa.Column("loc_id", sa.Integer),
  sa.PrimaryKeyConstraint("loc_id", "user_id"),
  sa.ForeignKeyConstraint(("loc_id",), ("location.loc_id",)),
  sa.ForeignKeyConstraint(("user_id",), ("user.user_id",)),
)
```

I want return next:

```
[
  {
    "username": "user_1",
    "locations": [... list of users loc_id ...]
  },
  {
    "username": "user_2",
    "locations": [... list of users loc_id ...]
  },
  ...
]
```

I tried something like:

```
db.query(User.username, User.locations).all()
```

but it doesen't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The relationship is accessible as an attribute on whichever model you're querying (provided your relationship is setup correctly). Your ask should look something like:

```
users = db.query(User).all()
# Alternatively you can filter on a specific user by using the following query:
users = db.query(User).filter(User.name == 'whatever name you want').all()
# Mimicking the actual list with dicts like you have above
user_list = list()
for u in users:
    user_list.append({'username': u.name, 'locations': [l.loc_id for l in u.locations})
```

If what I have above doesn't work I'd ask for further detail on those relationship attributes because it's possible those are misconfigured.